# In react-navigation How can i use two drawer in same screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

In react-navigation, I want to use two drawers on the same screen main drawer and a sub drawer in inner screens of the application. How can I create two different drawer stacks in the same application?

[image: here is the image I want to do]

Comment: Please share your code, at least the screens you will have. Also, you want 2 drawers from the same side our one in the left and another in the right?

Comment: I want to open two drawers from the same side one is main drawer and another will open when navigated to a particular screen. I want both the drawers from the right side.